# HTML parsing by perl script

Tags: html, perl, parsing, html-parsing, perl-module

I am trying to parse an HTML file through my perl script. I am using a module called HTML::TreeBuilder.

Here is what I have so far:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new; 

$tree->parse_file("sample.html");

foreach my $anchor ($tree->find("p")) {

  print $anchor->as_text, "\n";

}
```

It is working fine. I am getting everything inside `< p>` tag.

sample.html file:

```
< td>Release Version:< /td>< td> 5134< /td>< /tr>

< tr class="d0">< td>Executed By:< /td>< td>spoddar< /td>< /tr>

< tr class="d1">< td> Duration:< /td>< td>0 Hrs 0 Mins 0 Secs < /td>< /tr>

< tr class="d0">< td>#TCs Executed:< /td>< td>1< /td>< /tr>
```

I want `5134` to be printed when i pass Release Version.
In the same way I want `spoddar` to be printed when i pass Execute By.
These are not HTML tags. But is there any way to obtain this?

Comment: is there any rule that you need to apply when deciding what to print? should you print `0 Hrs 0 Mins 0 Secs`  also?

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward thing to do is to filter the tags you want and look through the text. The following approach assumes the format you have in the sample, with a 2-column table.

```
sub get_value {
    my $key = shift;

    foreach my $tr ($tree->find('tr')) {
        my @td = $tree->find('td');
        return $td[1]->as_text if $td[0]->as_text eq $key;
    }
    return;
}

print get_value('Release Version:');
```

Answer (score 2):

[HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm) and [HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm) may also be of use to you.

*UNTESTED*

```
use HTML::TokeParser;

my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new('sample.html');

while (my $token = $p->get_token) {
    my $tokenType = shift @{$token}; # 'S' is start tag 'E' end tag etc. (see doc)
    if ($tokenType =~ /S/) {
        my ($tag, $attr, $attrseq, $rawtxt) = @{$token};
        my $class = $attr->{class}; #get tag class
        if ($class =~ /d0/ && $tag =~ /tr/) {
            print "$p->get_trimmed_text('/tr')\n";
        }
    }
}
```